# Moqui ::: How to edit list using section iterator

Tags: moqui

We are trying to display data in a form-list field using section-iterate. Data is being displayed correctly. However, once updating fields, the list used in the section-iterator is not being updated.

**Sample code:**

```
<form-single name=“editTest”  transition=“editOneTest”>

<auto-fields-entity entity-name="test.Test” field-type="edit"/>
<field name="testDetails"><default-field>
<section-iterate name="TestDetailSection" list="testDetailList" entry="testDetail" >
        <condition>
            <compare field="testDetail.testId" operator="equals" to-field="testId"/>
        </condition>
        <widgets>
            <field name="hours">
                <default-field>
                    <text-find default-operator="equals" hide-options="true" default-value="${testDetail.hours}"    size="5" />
                </default-field>
            </field>
        </widgets>
    </section-iterate>
</default-field></field>
</form-single>
```

**Notes:**

We tried to declare list like  and add the hours edited in the new list. It didn't work.
I tried to create a script inside  of section-iterate to edit the testDetailList and didn't work.

Kindly, assit us to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the XSD (xml-screen-.xsd in this case) specified in your screen XML file and that your editor is validating the XML. The XML you've mentioned here is not valid.

The 'field' element cannot contain another field element, and a field element can't go under the 'widgets' element (it can only go under a default-field, conditional-field, or header-field element).

If you look at the HTML generated you'll see it has issues as the macros to transform XML to HTML do not support this sort of thing.